# SwiftUI and WidgetKit - Automatically updating components

Tags: text, swiftui, widget, updating, widgetkit

I am working with WidgetKit and I found that the text component initialised with `init(Date, style: Text.DateStyle)` is  creating automatically updating texts. This is something special because iOS widgets usually require to set a timeline about when to update the view. Unfortunately scheduling these updates is in the hands of the operating system, bases on a limited budget and thus, is unreliable.

Do you know about other SwiftUI views, that are automatically updating (and might also be passively updating in a widget)? Animated shapes would also be nice to have.

I have already tried using publishing timers, which won't work in widgets.

Comment: As of iOS14 there is only `public init(_ date: Date, style: Text.DateStyle)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date), the only self-updating SwiftUI view is `Text`, configured to display a relative date or time. See [Displaying Dynamic Dates in Widgets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/displaying-dynamic-dates) for details.

The options are:

```swift
Text(futureDate, style: .relative)
Text(futureDate, style: .offset)
Text(futureDate, style: .timer)
Text(aprilFirstDate, style: .date)
Text("Date: \(aprilFirstDate, style: .date)")
Text(startDate ... endDate)
Text("The meeting will take place: \(startDate ... endDate)")
```